# Windows Production server issues with web API

Tags: webapi

I am having weird situation on calling our internal API on our own production servers. We have 5 production servers. out of 5 servers only 2 servers returning API response and from antother 3 servers, the API response is null. I get 200 OK status only, however data is not populating from those 3 servers.

I can not replicate this issue on our QA and Pre-productions servers.

Appriciate your valuable inputs.

Thanks.

I checked all 5 web server logs. Those did not help me.